# Hide and then disable div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hide, opacity

I want to hide the div changing its opacity to 0 *with animation* and when it is done to disable it changing display property to *'none'*. Both functions should be started by onclick or at least one single action, so the div became invisible (like fade out) and then disappear.

---

I'm using this code to perform animation:

```
function animateStyle(divID) {
    $("#" + divID).css({ "opacity": "1" }).animate({ "opacity": "0" }, 900);
};

<span onclick="return animateStyle('alert-background');" 
class="close">&#10008;</span>
```

I tried to use *.hide* to disable div, but can't make both work together — if the animation works, then div doesn't disappear but only stays invisible. And if the div disappears, then animation doesn't work. May be there's a better solution for this idea?

---

**Update:**
I have found the way to do what I wanted, but it's more a trick then solution:

```
function animateStyle(divID) {
    $("#" + divID).css({ "opacity": "1" })
                  .animate({ "opacity": "0" }, 900)
                  .delay(1100)
                  .css({ "margin-top": "0" })
                  .animate({ "margin-top": "-100000px" }, 1);
};
```

But although this works right, I'd like to completely remove the div instead of moving it outside the screen. Hope there's a way to do it...

Comment: `$(function() { $('.close').on('click', function() { animateStyle($(this).data('id')); }); });` Add a data-attribute to animate the ID of your choosing.

Comment: But how should this disable the div? The point of my question is that I need both smooth animation while div becomes invisible (transparent) and then I need to disable this invisible div the same way as if its display property was 'none'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fadeOut`:

```
$("#" + divID).fadeOut(900);
```

It's supposed to be a shorthand to the following, which is closer to what you already have:

```
$("#" + divID).css({ "opacity": "1" }).animate({ "opacity": "0" }, {
    duration: 900,
    complete: function() { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Comment: .fadeOut doesn't make a smooth animation effect (for me at least).

Comment: That's weird. In theory, it should do exactly what you described. Added an alternative to my answer, try that and see if it performs smoother.

Comment: It seems strange to me also, but this doesn't give animation effect at least in Firefox and Chrome on mac.

Comment: And it looks like duration time here is actually delay time. Because when I increase it, it only makes a delay before the div disappears with no animation.

Comment: @KostseiKuolematon I may have found it: check your CSS or inline styles for `!important` rules on `opacity`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rGfGG/

Comment: Well, I don't have the animation effect in your jsfiddle, duration time is still  making a delay before div disappears without fading out. May be this doesn't work right on MacOS, but actually in Chrome on Windows it seems not to work at all...

Comment: @KostseiKuolematon That was the intention with that jsfiddle. I was trying to reproduce the problem you describe, and I did. As I said previously, inspect your target elements, and check if they have `!important` styles set. That could cause the animation to fail, as that fiddle demonstrates.

Comment: Ok, sorry, didn't get you right... But anyway I don't have !important styles.

Comment: I have a lot of different stuff on the page, may be something is conflicting with the fadeout because sometimes there's a kind of animation but it's not smooth and the layer disappears before it becomes completely transparent. You can take a look if you want: [link](http://thelocalgenius.com/test-2/)

Comment: Your CSS transitions are interfering with the fade out (at lest on your `alert-background`). Remove those and it works. Still weird fading out the background div instead of the alert itself...